# Is there any CSS hack to stop a dropdown menu from causing an overflow?

Tags: css, reactjs

**My problem:** https://i.gyazo.com/152caf74df3c484e770f9e8c34f5471e.mp4

If I click on the button, then it causes an overflow. I want to menu to appear without the overflow.

**Sandbox**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-8aq1rq?file=App.tsx,index.html

#### Code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { NavDropdown, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

// @ts-nocheck

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="table-responsive">
      <div className="table">
        <table
          id="user-list-table"
          className="table table-striped"
          role="grid"
          data-toggle="data-table"
        >
          <thead>
            <tr className="light">
              <th>Col one</th>
              <th>Col two</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>
                <NavDropdown
                  id="basic-nav-dropdown"
                  title={
                    <Button className="btn btn-sm btn-icon" variant="primary">
                      click
                    </Button>
                  }
                >
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Option 1</NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Option 2</NavDropdown.Item>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Option 3</NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there another bootstrap component that does this so that I can swap NavDropdown to it? If not, is there something else like a CSS hack that lets me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there isn't enough room to dropdown the nav list inside the div with the class of `table-responsive`.  You can give it some min height or padding, but that might be weird if you have content below it.  So you can add a negative margin to counter the additional padding:

```css
.table-responsive {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-58punl?file=App.tsx)

Comment: You're welcome.  Just make sure that you think about what happens at the bottom of the page.  You'll want to make sure that there's always enough space to display your dropdown.